# Is it safe to leave a JavaScript boolean variable uninitialised in this case?

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean

I have a variable `lightboxActive` to record if the lightbox for my gallery is currently on screen. The show function sets it to `true` and the hide function sets it to `false`.

I have declared it as `var lightboxActive = false;`. It's probable that the condition will be tested before either the show or hide events set a new value for `lightboxActive`, and I'm wondering is it OK to leave the variable uninitialised in its declaration, like `var lightboxActive;`?

I understand that an uninitialised variable holds the value `undefined`, and that `(undefined)` evaluates to `false` via an implicit cast to Boolean. My question is: is there an advantage to explicitly initialising the variable to `false`?

Comment: Are you doing strict comparison to boolean values or are you always using the variable in a way that will do a *toBoolean* conversion? Either way, why does it matter? Why not initialize it for clarity at the very least? What compels you to leave it uninitialized?

Comment: If a "falsy" value is all you need, and you don't actually need the boolean, it's not a problem.

Comment: If nothing else, explicitly initializing the variable will make your code a little clearer.  Code is written half for the computer, and half for the next programmer to come along.

Comment: *"...`undefined` evaluates to `false` via an implicit cast to Boolean*" Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Depends on how you're using it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. No advantage, then. Purely preference.

Comment: I believe that in the case I'm using it, like `if (varName)` then `undefined` evaluates to `false`. I am initialising it to `false`, but I was wondering if leaving it uninitialised would cause one of JavaScript's famous quirks in some edge case.